# Trying to set up a multiple criteria search and it is not working for me

Tags: python, django, model-view-controller

I'm currently trying to create a multiple criteria search on a webpage.  Here is the code I currently have:

**urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from app import views
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = patterns('',
url(r'^profile/$',views.profile),
)
```

**views.py**

```
def profile(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
    results = ThingModel.objects.all()

    th1 = request.POST.get('th1', None)
    if th1:
        results = results.filter(Thing1 = th1)

    th2 = request.POST.get('th2', None)
    if th2:
        results = results.filter(Thing2 = th2)

    th3 = request.POST.get('th3', None)
    if th3:
        results = results.filter(Thing3 = th3)

    num = request.POST.get('num', None)
    if num:
        results = results.filter(Number__gte = num)

    return render_to_response('profile.html', {'results': results})

return render(request,'profile.html')
```

**models.py**

```
class ThingModel(models.Model):    
    Thing1 = models.CharField(max_length=8, blank=True)
    Thing2 = models.CharField(max_length=8, blank=True)
    Thing3 = models.CharField(max_length=8, blank=True)
    Number = models.CharField(max_length=8, blank=True)
```

**profile.html**

```
<ul class="sidebar">
      <form action="." method="post">{% csrf_token %}
        <li>
            <span>Thing1:</span>
                <select name="th1">
                <option value="Selection 1">Selection 1</option>
                <option value="Selection 2">Selection 2</option>
                <option value="Selection 3">Selection 3</option>
            </select>
        </li>
        <li><span>Thing2:</span><input name="th2"></li>
        <li><span>Thing3:</span><input name="th3"></li>
        <li><span>Number:</span><input type="number" name="num"></li>
        <li><div><input type="submit" value="Go!"></div></li>
      </form>
</ul>
{% if results %}
   {% for n in results %}
   <table>
       <tr>{{n.Thing1}}</tr>
       <tr>{{n.Thing2}}</tr>
       <tr>{{n.Thing3}}</tr>
       <tr>{{n.Number}}</tr>
   </table>
   {% endfor %}        
{% else %}
  <p> Search for something to see the results! </p>
{% endif %}
```

Please help if you can - I have no idea what I am doing wrong.  When I click go, it stays on the search for something message.

Best,

Chris

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what about doing only one filter clause? Try this:

```
field_mapping = {
    'th1' : 'Thing1',
    'th2' : 'Thing2',
    'th3' : 'Thing3',
    'num' : 'Number__gte',
}
kwargs = {}
for post_param, kwarg_field in field_mapping.items():
    value = request.POST.get(post_param,None)
    if value:
        kwargs[kwarg_field] = value
results = ThingModel.objects.filter(**kwargs)
```

Comment: Thank you! Definitely getting much warmer-- the only thing is now it filters only one object or another, not two or more at the same time.

Comment: Passing criteria as kwargs acts as logical ANDs, so you may pass zero or 4 params, and it returs all or 4-ands records. Do you need OR clauses?

Comment: no i believe i need ANDs, its just that when i select something from the drop down box for thing1 that doesnt match anything in the database and search, nothing comes up (which is what i want to happen); but, if select that same thing1 and search for number_gte, it just fills results with everything that "num" is greater than or equal to.

Comment: also added a field for Number_lte and that doesn't filter for anything less than or equal to.  Would that be the proper way to search within a range of numbers?

Comment: Could you add a print(kwargs) in your code? For what you say, seems that some input sends its value and it isn't blank. For number ranges you must use __gte and __lte filters together

Comment: I actually figured it out-- I used a combination of the code you gave me with some extra filters of results to get it to work.  Thanks a lot man, would've never figured this out without your help!